# Python - Running an pip installed package from cli

Tags: python, bash, pip

I just came across a [pip package I want to use](https://pypi.org/project/openapi-cli-tool/) however I'm new to python and PIP and not sure - is it possible to run that directly from terminal/the command line. If so, I can't seem to find the syntac to run a pip package.

So I installed pip using:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

then

```
python get-pip.py
```

I then checked installation, by the command `python -m pip`

I then installed the package like:

```
python -m pip install openapi-cli-tool
```

Anyhow, as per the docs of that package I though I could just do:

```
openapi-cli-tool bundle -t html file1.json file2.yaml` > ./specification.html
```

Which didn't work, neither did this:

```
python -p pip openapi-cli-tool bundle -t html file1.json file2.yaml` > ./specification.html
```

Any help in explaining how this works would be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain "*didn't work*".

Answer (score 0):

You have to install it with pip, run command below:

```
pip install openapi-cli-tool
```

Then `openapi-cli-tool` will be available in your terminal, so you shall be able to run command, the command below is with correction of parameters passing:

Make sure you have file1.json and file2.yaml in file system.

```
openapi-cli-tool bundle -t html file1.json file2.yaml` > ./specification.html
```

Comment: I see `command not found: pip` I need to use `python -m pip` each time

Comment: also, do you have file1.json file2.yaml in your file system ?

Comment: Yes I have those files

Comment: And `pip install openapi-cli-tool` also says `command not found: pip` - I need to install with `python -m pip install openapi-cli-tool`

Comment: Try to run `sudo python get-pip.py` to install pip

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214654/discussion-between-usermod2-and-andriy-ivaneyko).

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m pip install
```

Installs the package to the user's local directory (iirc)

So, you can access it from `~/.local/bin/`, like this:

```
~/.local/bin/openapi-cli-tool bundle -t html file1.json file2.yaml` > ./specification.html
```

You can add `~/.local/bin` to your path by

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin
```

and probably add that line to your `.bashrc` or it's equivalent.

Then, you can access it by just `openapi-cli-tool bundle`